# Error 438 When Saving Attachments using Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I pieced this together for saving all Excel attachments from incoming mail to a local drive folder.

It is in the ThisOutlookSession module and I restarted Outlook.

When I send a test email meeting the criteria in the If statements, I receive >"Error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method".

I can't figure out which object doesn't support which property or method.

It is at least running up to my If statements because this only happens to emails that meet the criteria.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents inboxItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objectNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set inboxItems = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub inboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem

Dim i As Integer
Dim strFolder As String
Dim mySaveName As String
Dim myExt As String
Dim OlMail As Outlook.MailItem

strFolder = "D:\Scripts\VendorProductivity\Daily files"

If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
    If Item.Subject Like "*Report*" Then
        If Item.Recipient = "Jane Doe" Then
            If Item.Attachments.Count > 0 Then

                'loop through all attachments
                For i = 1 To Item.Attachments.Count

                   mySaveName = Item.Attachments.Item(i).FileName
                   myExt = Split(mySaveName, ".")(1)

                   'Only save files with named extensions
                   Select Case myExt
                       Case "xls", "xlsm", "xlsx"
                           mySaveName = strFolder & "\" & mySaveName
                           Item.Attachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile mySaveName

                       Case Else
                           'do nothing
                   End Select
                Next
                Item.Delete
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If

ExitNewItem:
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ExitNewItem
End Sub
```

Comment: Which statement gives the error?

Comment: Please delete `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler` which will conceal which statement is causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

`MailItem` does not expose a property named `Recipient` (singular). It exposes a property named `Recipients` (plural), but is is not a string property - it is a collection of `Recipient` objects, which expose `Name` and `Address` properties among others.

Did you mean to use the `SenderName` property instead?